# Convert list of dicts to string

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I'm very new to Python, so forgive me if this is easier than it seems to me.

I'm being presented with a list of dicts as follows:

```
[{'directMember': 'true', 'memberType': 'User', 'memberId': 'address1@example.com'},  
 {'directMember': 'true', 'memberType': 'User', 'memberId': 'address2@example.com'},  
 {'directMember': 'true', 'memberType': 'User', 'memberId': 'address3@example.com'}]
```

I would like to generate a simple string of memberIds, such as

> address1@example.com,
>   address2@example.com,
>   address3@example.com

but every method of converting a list to a string that I have tried fails because dicts are involved.

Any advice?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
', '.join(d['memberId'] for d in my_list)
```

Since you said you are new to Python, I'll explain how this works.

The [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method combines each element of an iterable (like a list), and uses the string that the method is called on as the separator.

The iterable that is provided to the method is the generator expression `(d['memberId'] for d in my_list)`.  This essentially gives you each element that would be in the list created by the list comprehension `[d['memberId'] for d in my_list]` without actually creating the list.

Answer (score 8):

These one-liners are ok but a beginner might not get it. Here they are broken down:

```
list_of_dicts = (the list you posted)
```

Ok, we have a list, and each member of it is a dict. Here's a `list comprehension`:

```
[expr for d in list_of_dicts]
```

This is like saying `for d in list_of_dicts ...`. `expr` is evaluated for each d and a new list is generated. You can also select just some of them with `if`, see the docs.

So, what `expr` do we want? In each dict `d`, we want the value that goes with the key `'memberId'`. That's `d['memberId']`. So now the list comprehension is:

```
[d['memberId'] for d in list_of_dicts]
```

This gives us a list of the email addresses, now to put them together with commas, we use `join` (see the docs):

```
', '.join([d['memberId'] for d in list_of_dicts])
```

I see the other posters left out the [] inside `join`'s argument list, and it works. Have to look that up, I don't know why you can leave it out. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Access the dicts.

```
', '.join(d['memberId'] for d in L)
```